# Windows startup internet problem

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet, lan

I am on shared LAN internet coming from some other admin computer. Most of the time when i start the computer i see the two monitors icon signaling that lan is connected. However sometimes when i start my computer that icon does not appear and i am unable to connect to internet even though signals in my device are coming full then the only solution is to restart the computer. Isn't there a way to bring that icon back and connect to the internet. Also any suggestion on why it doesn't appear on windows startup.

I have up to date antivirus Avira
Win XP SP2

Comment: fyi - XP sp2 has reached end of life. It is no longer supported and will no longer get new security patches.  You should update it to service pack 3.  This is a free update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a number of things and unfortunately, without seeing the machine, it is hard to advise.

The first thing I would do is check for a driver update for your network card as I have seen problems like this in the past.

Next, I would check that the adapter is being correctly discovered as if it is internal, there could be some sort of hardware problem - Right click on `My Computer` to go to `Computer Management` and then expand device manager and make sure it is listed under `Network Adapters`  AND there is no sort of yellow triangle - if there is a triangle, try to see what the error is.

If it does not show under Device Manager, take a look in the system event log as you should see a few warnings.

Lastly, if it is found but there is just some random error - try going to `Control Panel` > `Network Adapters` then right clicking on your device and choose `Disable` then re-enable it.

As an extra, sometimes DHCP can just mess up in some environments - it may be worth trying to assign a static address to your machine as it is possible that everything is working but DHCP is not assigning a correct address. Without seeing your network, I can't say what address to try.

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 monitors are an indicator of a network connection.  If you have no connection on boot, it is likely an issue with your network or your NIC (network interface card).  I am guessing your NIC is the issue.

The next time this happens, go to

`Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Network Connections`

and see what is listed.  If there is no connection listed, the PC is not seeing your network card and you likely need a replacement.